# How to submit form data to backend?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, user-interface, frontend

Disclaimer: I’m a backend programmer and I would like to minimize javascript code in my webpages.

I’m considering using the login form given [here](https://fomantic-ui.com/examples/login.html) as example. In this example we have this

```
<form class="ui large form">
  <div class="ui stacked segment">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="user icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="lock icon"></i>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui error message"></div>
</form>
```

The login button is just a div which does nothing. There is no action argument in the form tag and there is no submit type input tag.

How do I get the page to send the input field values back to the backend server ?

Note that there is some javascript code visible in the source page that checks the validity of the fields. But there is no hint on how to get send the email and password to the backend and load the logged in page.

Comment: Is there something which prevents you from manipulating the DOM?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: "The login button is just a div which does nothing. There is no action argument in the form tag and there is no submit type input tag." Why not? These are the basics of HTML Forms and it sounds like you are willingly and flagrantly flouting them. If you want things to work, use them according to [the instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms)

Comment: @Quentin I understand the argument. We could add to it that the hardly readable placeholder value does not respect accessibility rules. But in this case, the icons in front of the text fields give a visual queue on the expected content. It is the same with a seach field if the icon was a magnifying glass. But for a more general form with multiple fields, I definitely agree with the argument.

Comment: @chmike — If you want to label a form control with an image, then that is fine. `<label for="field_id"><img src="mag.png" alt="Search"></label>`.

Comment: @quentin with the fomantic-ui framework, the <i> tag inserts an icon. It's not obvious, I know.

Comment: @chmike — It's not accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The login button is just a div which does nothing

Make it a `<button>`.

> There is no action argument in the form tag

Add one if you want the data to be submitted to a *different* URL then that of the current page.

Your form should also be `method="POST"`. Passwords do not belong in URLs (which are often logged in plain text).

> How do I get the page to send the input field values back to the backend server ?

Use a `<button>` element to represent your submit button and not a `<div>` element. The `<div>` element is when you need a block element and HTML lacks an element with the semantics to describe your content. That isn't the case here, you want to submit a form and that is what submit buttons are for.

Comment: This is impressive. It worked just by adding the action parameter and method. No need to change the div into button. I have no idea why. It is using the fomantic-ui framework and it has an input validation script. They might have some javascript magic associated to the submit class. Is the button tag just a convention, or is it needed ? How can it work without this button tag ?

Comment: I have another question. In this example, there is only one button. What if I wanted to have two buttons. How could I tell which button was pressed. We can solve this with submit input types by adding the name and value parameters. But this doesn’t work with this div. EDIT: it works when I change the tag to button. I can add a name and value parameters and they are passed with the form values.